# How to run a python script with Python Tools for Visual Studio in a virtualenv?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010, ptvs

I don't know how to run the activate.bat in a Python Tools for Visual Studio Project. I have a directory environment in my project with my virtualenv. But, I don't know how I can run `./env/Scripts/activate.bat` before the project run my main python script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that if :

- main.py is set as Startup File,
- in the Properties of the project -> Debug tab -> Interpreter Path field, I put the path C:...\env\Scripts\python.exe (i.e. the python executable of the virtualenv)

It works !

Comment: Your question was **how I can run ./env/Scripts/activate.bat**, you've unaccepted my answer, posted your own answer that isn't relevant to the initial question, and then accepted it. Bad form.

Comment: I prefer this answer from balmat : not tampering the source, just the environment.

Comment: Nice! However, it's not necessary to have the startup script called main.py. You only need to point the interpreter into the virtualenv, as you said.

Comment: Hi @Balmat, How to set main.py as Startup File?

Answer (score 4):

I usually point Visual Studio to a custom `startup.py` script, any other batch files I can then run using:

```
# startup.py
import os
import main.py # Whatever your main script is
os.system('activate.bat') # Call your batch files.
main.run() # Call whatever you need to from your main script.
```

In Visual Studio

- Right click on project
- Properties
- General
- Under *Startup File*, put `startup.py`  *(whatever)*
- Make sure your working directory is correct

Comment: I'd say, @balmat own answer is most appropriate (and straightforward) for the his question

Answer (score 4):

Python Tools for Visual Studio(PTVS) 2.0 is out now, in it you can add a virtualenv.

1. Open the Solution Explorer: View > Solution Explorer
2. Right click on 'Python Environments' and choose 'Add Virtual
   Environment'

[Here is a video showing how to do it.](https://youtu.be/JNNAOypc6Ek?t=12m57s)

Answer (score 1):

Full support for Virtual Env is coming in PTVS 2.0 Beta/RTM.  See http://pytools.codeplex.com for news/updates.  Early support is in PTVS 2.0 Alpha, available now.